# Post Website On Github Pages Without Exposing API Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, api-key

I created a ReactJS movie website with TMDb movie API and my website fetches data from TMDb server which requires an API key. I have created an .env file and put my API key there and then I added that .env file to my .gitignore file, but now I want to publish my website on github pages without publicly exposing my API key, please help me by suggesting solution to this particular problem.

I have found many questions regarding how to hide my API key, but here, what I am asking is that, how to publish my page with my API key not being publicly accessible.

Comment: Your API key will always be exposed, if it ever touches the user's end (aka. the frontend). There will always be a way to dig it out. The only way to not expose the API key is to have some kind of backend to your site/application, which you can call from your frontend without the key and your backend would then use the API key it internally has and return the result. If you have to use an API key on the frontend, you'd have to be able to configure and restrict the usage of the API key to allow its use only from your domain. If this is not possible, then your options are pretty limited.

Comment: Furthermore, with Github Pages, there is unfortunately no way to do this without exposing the API key.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usecase, you could use [GitHub actions](https://github.com/helaili/jekyll-action) and GitHub secrets to achieve this.

The action could fetch data from the API, making it [available during the build](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/#workflow-management). This would almost be like cache warming, fetching upstream data and storing a static version closer to the client. Depending on your usecase, I think something like that would work.

Comment: No, it won't work if the user is supposed to be able to e.g. type in a name of a movie and have the application fetch it.

Comment: Shoot. Yes, like the others have said, if you absolutely need to perform a search from the client to the API, it is unlikely you can hide your API key.

Answer (score -1):

Github Pages are supposed to be `public` for community/free tier.
Remove the API key from the code, where ever it is. Store API key as a variable in Github `Secrets`.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

And then, reference it during pipeline build with `${{ secrets.API_KEY }}`

Update your `.env` file with this key.

Add .env to .gitignore

Comment: That won't help - see the comment by Swiffy.